# How do i show that there exists $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that a given matrix is not a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

Let $x \in [0,2\pi)$.

Define $A_x = \left (\begin{matrix} \cos(x) & -\sin(x) & 0&0 \\ \sin(x) & \cos (x) & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cos(x) & -\sin(x) \\ 0& 0& \sin(x) & \cos(x) \end{matrix} \right)$.

Then $\forall x\in [0,2\pi), A_x$ is well defined.

My question is, does there exist some $x\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $A_x$ is not a rotation? Here is my definition of rotation:

> An orthogonal operator $T$ on a nonzero real inner product space $V$ is a rotation if
>
> 1. $T$ is the identity map, or
> 2. there exists a 2-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$, an orthonormal basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ for $W$ and some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that
>      \begin{cases}
>    T(x_1) = \cos(\theta)x_1+ \sin(\theta)x_2,\\
>    T(x_2) = -\sin(\theta)x_1 + \cos(\theta)x_2,\\
>    T(y)=y\ \text{ for all }\ y\in W^{\perp}.
>    \end{cases}

Comment: For every $0<x<2\pi$ $A_x\neq Id$ and so your second requirement is not true for any $W^\perp$.

Comment: So in other words your definition of a rotation is that it acts as a rotation in some two dimensional subspace, and fixes the complementary subspace?

Comment: this question comes finding an example that a composite of two rotations is not a rotation on 4-dimensional space

Comment: @rschwieb exatly!

Comment: @Sigur I don't understand why $W^{\perp}$ does not satisfy the second requirement. Could you explain this briefly?

Comment: Because *both* $W$ and $W^\perp$ are being rotated.

Comment: The effect of $A_x$ on $W$ is the same as on its complement.

Comment: Since your transformation preserves length, so let's see only on the unitary sphere. You can consider the $3$-sphere $S^3$ as the curved join of two circles $S^1\ast S^1$. So your map is rotating both circles so the effect on $S^3$ does not leave the second $S^1$ fixed.

Comment: @Sigur After more thinking I decided my comment wasn't necessary.  I think it's easy to argue what you said is also sufficient :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to detect if the transformation is leaving the orthogonal complement alone is to check the eigenvalues. If it really is leaving a two dimensional subspace invariant, it should have eigenvalue 1 with at least multiplicity 2.

A computation shows that the eigenvalues are $\cos(x)\pm i\sin(x)$, each of them having multiplicity two. So, the only way there can be an invariant subspace of dimension at least 2 is for $x=0$, when you get the identity.

I guess, as you hinted in the comments above, that this matrix results as a composition of $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(x)&-\sin(x)&0&0\\\sin(x)&\cos(x)&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&\cos(x)&-\sin(x)\\0&0&\sin(x)&\cos(x)\end{bmatrix}$$

You can easily see that these matrices individually have two-dimensional eigenspaces for the eigenvalue $1$. The other part of the requirement for rotations about two orthonormal vectors is fulfilled by the columns containing sines and cosines.